# Unexpected token error while using javascript snippet with WPCode in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages, code-snippets

I am trying to add custom javascript into my website for a widget on wordpress using the wpcode plugin but I keep getting an unexpected token error. There is a  already created that isn't accessible in the text box where you add the code. Here is the line of javascript:

```
<script src="https://apis.owenscorning.com/client/widget.js" async></script>
```

I've tried deleting the opening  and leaving the "src=" in hopes of it accepting the script that is inaccessible but the unexpected token error doesn't go away.

Comment: `Here is the line of javascript:` - that's HTML - anyway, there is no error when loading that script - what makes you think that script is the source of the error? Did you put that HTML in the middle of javascript?

Comment: Here is the link to what I am trying to add: https://www.owenscorning.com/en-us/roofing/widgets/shingle-widget @JaromandaX It says its javascript. If not I can add it as html and see if that works. Thank you

Comment: huh? what do you mean add it as html? I think you're confused

Comment: Yes, I was very confused. I did figure it out. Your solution worked. I really appreciate you answering the question. You are the real MVP @JaromandaX

Comment: I didn't supply a solution though, I suggested you that you may have put the tag in the middle of some javascript - is that what you fixed?

Comment: I ended up putting that line of code in the wpcode's "footer" section which is at the bottom of the <body> closing tag. The reason I say your solution worked is because you made me question how I was doing it before. So instead of using the javascript section of the plugin, I used to footer section instead and it worked. Which is essentially what the answer down below says to do. You're owed a thank you and you WILL take it. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's the script tag which you would normally place in the `<head>` tag of your html file.  However, that script of you paste that url into the browser you'll see its a self executing widget code.  Since that code looks for the head tag on the document etc.  I would like to recommend you place that script of code right at the bottom of your `<body>` closing tag:

E.g.

```
<body>
 ....[other code here]....
  <script src="https://apis.owenscorning.com/client/widget.js"></script>
</body>
```